# Index Match function in Excel with multiple horizontal criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

Hope someone can help me with the following Excel task:

Somehow I cannot make it work:

[image]

Formula:

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$16,MATCH(F$1,$B$2:$B$16,0),MATCH($E2,$A$2:$A$16,0))
```

I guess it has something to do with an array formula as it only works one-directional. Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Just going off your sample data,

you could just use a SUMIFS rather than INDEX & MATCH

Enter the below into F2, then drag across and down:

```
=SUMIFS($C:$C,$A:$A,$E2,$B:$B,F$1)
```

`INDEX` works by going down then across, using `MATCH` tells it how far down and across to go.

I.e

- =INDEX(A1:E5,1,1) would give you the value in A1,
- =INDEX(A1:E5,5,1) would give you the value in A5,
- =INDEX(A1:E5,5,5) would give you the value in E5,